Theatre.js + Three.js - Change animation rate
I tried to write a code, the meaning of which is as follows: when the animation is active (we hover the mouse over the object and hold it), we remove the mouse from the object and the animation should play forward a little, gradually slowing down, then smoothly change its direction in the opposite direction.

raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera) determines the intersection with the object
if (intersects.length > 0) InteractiveOn();
InteractiveOnn() { name.sequence.play ({direction: 'normal', rate: 1}) }
Remove the mouse and raycaster.setFromCamera activates InteractiveOff()
InteractiveOff(): smooth change of rate to ~0 > change of animation direction:
name.sequence.play ({direction: 'reverse', rate: 1})

I wrote the following code:
function TM_Func_ChangeRate() {
    let start = performance.now();

    function timing(t) {
        return t < 0.5 ? 2 * t * t : -1 + (4 - 2 * t) * t;
    }

    function TM_Func_GradualChange(time) {
        if (!TM_Fl_RateChange) return; 

        let timeFraction = (time - start) / 100;
        if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

        let progress = TM_Fl_Direction === 'forward'
            ? timing(timeFraction)
            : timing(1.01 - timeFraction);

        TM_SQ_Rate = Math.max(progress, 0.01);

        if (timeFraction < 1) {
            TM_changeRateId = requestAnimationFrame(TM_Func_GradualChange);
        } else {
            TM_Fl_RateChange = false;
            TM_changeRateId = null;
        }
    }

    TM_Fl_RateChange = true; 
    TM_changeRateId = requestAnimationFrame(TM_Func_GradualChange);
}


function TM_InteractiveOn() {
    if (!TM_Fl_isHovered) {
        TM_Fl_isHovered = true;
        
        if (TM_Sequence.position === 0) {
            TM_Fl_playForward = true;
            TM_SQ_Direction = 'normal';
            TM_SQ_Rate = 1;
            start_TM_Animation({
                direction: TM_SQ_Direction,
                rate: TM_SQ_Rate
            });
        } else {
        //    TM_SQ_Direction = 'reverse';
            TM_Fl_RateChange = false;
            cancelAnimationFrame(TM_changeRateId);
            TM_changeRateId = null;
            TM_Fl_Direction = 'back';
            TM_Func_ChangeRate();
            if (TM_stopTimeout) clearTimeout(TM_stopTimeout);
            TM_stopTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                if (!TM_Fl_playForward) {
                    TM_Fl_playForward = true;
                    
                    TM_SQ_Direction = 'normal';
                    TM_Fl_Direction = 'forward';

                    TM_Fl_RateChange = false;
                    cancelAnimationFrame(TM_changeRateId);
                    TM_changeRateId = null;
                    TM_Func_ChangeRate();

                    start_TM_Animation({TM_SQ_Direction, TM_SQ_Rate});
                }
            }, 100); 
        }

    }
}


function TM_InteractiveOff() {
    if (TM_Fl_isHovered) {
        TM_Fl_isHovered = false;
        
        if (TM_Sequence.position === 1.5) {
            TM_Fl_playForward = false;
            TM_SQ_Direction = 'reverse';
            TM_SQ_Rate = 1;
            start_TM_Animation({
                direction: TM_SQ_Direction,
                rate: TM_SQ_Rate
            });
        } else {
        //    TM_SQ_Direction = 'normal';
            TM_Fl_RateChange = false;
            cancelAnimationFrame(TM_changeRateId);
            TM_changeRateId = null;
            TM_Fl_Direction = 'back';
            TM_Func_ChangeRate();
            if (TM_stopTimeout) clearTimeout(TM_stopTimeout);
            TM_stopTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                if (!TM_Fl_playForward) {
                    TM_Fl_playForward = false;
                    
                    TM_SQ_Direction = 'reverse';
                    TM_Fl_Direction = 'forward';

                    TM_Fl_RateChange = false;
                    cancelAnimationFrame(TM_changeRateId);
                    TM_changeRateId = null;
                    TM_Func_ChangeRate();

                    start_TM_Animation({TM_SQ_Direction, TM_SQ_Rate});
                }
            }, 100); 
        }

    }
}


function start_TM_Animation({ TM_SQ_Direction, TM_SQ_Rate }) {
    TM_Sequence.play({
        range: [0, 1.5],
        iterationCount: 1,
        direction: TM_SQ_Direction,
        rate: TM_SQ_Rate,
    });
} 

But for some reason the code doesn't work properly at all: the animation plays forward and freezes. Even if we remove the mouse during the animation, the animation will still continue to its end and freeze :(

Hi, You have provided code which is excellent but your question is unclear and should have a specific question. If I have read your question correctly, a suggested re-write is:
The following code should allow a user to activate an animation by hovering the mouse over it. If the mouse is removed the animation should slow down, stop and then reverse but this is not working. When the mouse is hovering the animation slows down and freezes. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

@strattonn. Thank you for your interest. Let me try to explain again: it is necessary to find a method for dynamically changing the rate in the "TM_Sequence.play" sequence. But as far as I understand, theater.js accepts the specified parameters at the moment of animation launch and saves them until the next animation call, regardless of whether you will simultaneously change them in other lines of code (for example, as I tried to change the rate via requestAnimFrame). That is why I wrote that the objects were stuck, although in fact they were simply animated with direction: reverse, rate: 0.01

@strattonn Therefore, most likely, as I assume, the solution to my problem lies in creating additional slowdown animations in the sequence: conditionally, if the TM_DoorL object has turned 50 degrees, then at the moment when the mouse is removed, we launch the animation TM_Sequence.play({range: [*sequence fragment, where slowdown and burst animation are implemented through keys and curves]}).
